# How do I get the output of an object which has more than one line in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, join, dictionary, grep

```
@ver = $session->cmd("sh conf");
```

The variable here is `ver`, which has the configuration file, that is, it has more than one line. So how to take an output of each line of the `ver` variable without putting it in a loop?

Comment: What do you mean 'take output'? You have the output, but it's in an array form.

Comment: It would help if you told us what $session was. Any method can decide for itself what to return in the various contexts. What happens if you assign to a scalar instead of an array? Also, remember to show complete example programs so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

Your `@var` variable is an array - each element will contain one line.

You cannot get all lines without (implicitly or explicitly) looping over the entire array.

You can have perl do all the work for you though - for example, using `join`, `grep` or `map`, depending what you want.

Examples:

```
#print all lines to a webpage
print join('<br />',@ver);

#print all lines with the word 'error' in it
print grep(/error/,@ver);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
print join("\n", @ver);
```